Cucumber Error to attach image using scenario.attach for Parallel Run
I use scenario.attach for image for some steps in StepDefinitions class, and it works perfectly in sequential run.
But when I started to run in Parallel, I started to get the error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: You can not use Scenario.log or Scenario.attach when a step is not being executed"
Any idea on this issue and how to fix it for Parallel run?
Have tried several ways but not working

Cucumber Java version: 7.18.0
Selenium version: 4.22.0
TestNG version: 7.10.2


Using selenium-shutterbug version 1.6 to take full screen, and attach using scenario.attach(img, "image/png", "");

Error I've gotten:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: You can not use Scenario.log or Scenario.attach when a step is not being executed
at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestCaseState.requireActiveTestStep(TestCaseState.java:157)
at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestCaseState.attach(TestCaseState.java:73)
at io.cucumber.java.Scenario.attach(Scenario.java:78)
at stepdefs.VerificationStepDefs.error_message_displayed(VerificationStepDefs.java:155)


can you add the appropriate tag for the system or the tool you are using. And maybe add additional information like version number?

@ruud added some info, hope it helps.

Can you show the stack trace? And the parts of your code that the stack trace passes through?

Right now it sounds like you are sharing state between scenarios by accident. Possibly because you're storing data in static variables. And you might be using static variables because you want to share data between different step definition files. Use dependency injection to share state between step definition file instead instead. https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-picocontainer

@M.P.Korstanje i think probably due to the static variable. I have a Hook class with static scenario variable across the step definitions. The initiation of the scenario in @Before annotation method and it's static.
Let me edit the question and put the stack trace there
